# php how to loop value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following php code:

```
$range=range(1,$count);
$value=implode(",",$range);
$query1="SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura FROM creeazafactura WHERE numar_factura IN ($value)";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);

while ($rowx = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $getvalue[]=$rowx['numar_factura'];
}
$missingvalue = array_diff($range,$getvalue);

print_r($range);
print_r($getvalue);
print_r($missingvalue);
```

with the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

Array
(
    [2] => 3
)
```

what i'm trying to figure out is, how to do so that the following line

```
printf("WARNING: The invoice $missing[2] is missing.");
```

will work always. Why i'm telling always? Because now id deleted the 3rd invoice, but if i delete the second invoice i will have array[1] to output in $missing

The answer is to make a loop so that i will have in the printf the $missing[$loop],

where the loop is searching for one or two invoices deleted.. and output 1 or two lines.

Easy to say, hard to do, when you are a beginner and you want to do an easy invoice system for a friend who uses excel :)

If you could provide some examples, or some links to some documentation, you could do me a great favor. Thank you

Comment: Consider removing unnecessary codes from your question. Then you will get good answers.

Comment: so you want code to loop over $missingvalue and print using prinf right?

Comment: @saranbanerjee: even echo is ok, not only printf, and yes the output to be from a loop from where is getting all the missing numbers.

Comment: @Red: sorry, first time on stackoverflow, even if until now 99% of the problem building the php code has come with solution from the memebers of this site :) , will try to clean a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
foreach($missingvalue as $key => $value)
{
    printf('WARNING: The invoice '.$value.' is missing.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Saran. I have the same output as in the other example. Try every possibility and it's not working. I think the problem is that i have an loop with the while function, and now i do another which take only the first value. Boh, it's over my knowledge, but i will try to dig the while and foreach function deeper.

Comment: can you tell what error is coming right after doing the foreach?

Comment: done some modifications, and taken step by step with the print_r and check the code... and after I've tested, it's seem that your code is working as expected. Thank you all for all the great answers.

Thank you saran banerjee

Answer (score 0):

So aim is to get the ID of a missing invoice.
Try this:

```
// here's your missing invoice array
$missingvalue = array_diff($range,$getvalue);
// get keys of it
$missingvalue_keys = array_keys($missingvalue);
// and now get the value from $missingvalue by key from $missingvalue_keys
printf('WARNING: The invoice ' . $missing[$missingvalue_keys[0]] . ' is missing.');

// if you have multiple values in $missingvalue than you dont need keys
foreach ($missingvalue as $value)
    printf('WARNING: The invoice ' . $value . ' is missing.');
// or with implode
printf('WARNING: The invoices ' . implode(',', $missingvalue) 
        . ' are missing.');
```

Comment: in the first example even if i corrected $missing, with $missing value, has give me some error, then deleted the [0] and always some error... not important because i could have more than one invoice missing..

in the second example with foreach, is going 50%.. the problem is that with the invoice 3 deleted is giving me the 3 is missing, but if i delete the second is giving me only the 2 is missing... but is working

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in /var/www/../index2.php on line 51  then if i delete the [0] - Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/../index2.php on line 51

Comment: Try to `print_r($missingvalue_keys)` and see what it contains. I'll check out `printf`, maybe it's the cause of error.

Comment: print_r($missingvalue_keys); is containing   Array ( [0] => 1 )  now from the 4 invoices the 2 and 3 is deleted, it remain only 1 and 4 ...

Comment: Edited once agian without unnecessary `_keys`